# efficient, fast numpy histograms

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, histogram

I have a 2D numpy array consisting of ca. 15'000'000 datapoints. Each datapoint has a timestamp and an integer value (between 40 and 200). I must create histograms of the datapoint distribution (16 bins: 40-49, 50-59, etc.), sorted by year, by month within the current year, by week within the current year, and by day within the current month.

Now, I wonder what might be the most efficient way to accomplish this. Given the size of the array, performance is a conspicuous consideration. I am considering nested "for" loops, breaking down the arrays by year, by month, etc. But I was reading that numpy arrays are highly memory-efficient and have all kinds of tricks up their sleeve for fast processing. So I was wondering if there is a faster way to do that. As you may have realized, I am an amateur programmer (a molecular biologist in "real life") and my questions are probably rather naïve.

Answer (score 2):

First, fill in your 16 bins without considering date at all.
Then, sort the elements within each bin by date.
Now, you can use binary search to efficiently locate a given year/month/week within each bin.

Answer (score 2):

In order to do this, there is a function in `numpy`, `numpy.bincount`. It is blazingly fast. It is so fast that you can create a bin for each integer (161 bins) and day (maybe 30000 different days?) resulting in a few million bins.

The procedure:

- calculate an integer index for each bin (e.g. 17 x number of day from the first day in the file + (integer - 40)//10)
- run `np.bincount`
- reshape to the correct shape (number of days, 17)

Now you have the binned data which can then be clumped into whatever bins are needed in the time dimension.

Without knowing the form of your input data the integer bin calculation code could be something like this:

```
# let us assume we have the data as:
#   timestamps: 64-bit integer (seconds since something)
#   values: 8-bit unsigned integer with integers between 40 and 200

# find the first day in the sample
first_day = np.min(timestamps) / 87600

# we intend to do this but fast:
indices = (timestamps / 87600 - first_day) * 17 + ((values - 40) / 10)

# get the bincount vector
b = np.bincount(indices)

# calculate the number of days in the sample
no_days = (len(b) + 16) / 17

# reshape b
b.resize((no_days, 17))
```

It should be noted that the first and last days in `b` depend on the data. In testing this most of the time is spent in calculating the indices (around 400 ms with an i7 processor). If that needs to be reduced, it can be done in approximately 100 ms with `numexpr` module. However, the actual implementation depends really heavily on the form of timestamps; some are faster to calculate, some slower.

However, I doubt if any other binning method will be faster if the data is needed up to the daily level.

I did not quite understand it from your question if you wanted to have separate views on the (one by year, ony by week, etc.) or some other binning method. In any case that boils down to summing the relevant rows together.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, employing the group_by functionality found in the link below:
http://pastebin.com/c5WLWPbp

```
import numpy as np

dates = np.arange('2004-02', '2005-05', dtype='datetime64[D]')

np.random.shuffle(dates)

values = np.random.randint(40,200, len(dates))

years  = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64[Y]')
months = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64[M]')
weeks  = np.array(dates, dtype='datetime64[W]')


from grouping import group_by

bins = np.linspace(40,200,17)

for m, g in zip(group_by(months)(values)):
    print m
    print np.histogram(g, bins=bins)[0]
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at the pandas package, which probably has an elegant solution to this problem as well.